# Can the answer suggest a supplement which is not in the first line of therapy?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since my answer has been [removed](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/570/114) and probable reason includes that:

> You are prescribing appetite suppressant where the first line of therapy is dietary modification and exercise. Also they are not indicated in this BMI range.

My question is, **can the answer may suggest a supplement** which is:

- supported/backup up by studies (with reliable links to sources),
- questioner already talked to a specialist and he's aware of standard procedures,
- links to any known side effects and relevant information

?

For example asking for **any** good diets or therapy for common metabolic disorder.

Please be aware that first line of therapy can be vary from country to country and since the site is worldwide, I think it shouldn't restrict the suggestion to only such therapies.

What do you think?