# Shortcut for Request to Include sources

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As was decided in [this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), answers on Health.SE **must** be backed up with verifiable references, sources or evidence.

Because this is different in comparison to many other stack-exchange sites, some new members and, strangely enough, even old members seem to have trouble remembering this.

An example of such an answer is the following:

```
   Brain injury is caused by drinking too much water, which can be quite lethal. 
   Many people have died although they drank 2l of water daily. (1)
```

It is quite tiring to always type the same comment over and over again. Just as we have a shortcut for `[chat]`, `[tour]`, could we also have a shortcut for `[sources]`. I could imagine that this looks like the following:

> Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has
>   a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with
>   reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers), in order to provide the community with the
>   means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's
>   background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

---

(1): This is obviously stupid and just made up, so that you can get the impression of what answers we are talking about. *Note* that they may actually be correct but are just not backed up with evidence etc.

Comment: If you wish to not identify the answer, you should just make one up. I found your "not easily identifiable" in about 5 seconds. :)

Comment: I like this idea, I will talk with one of the other mods, I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @JohnP and other mods: Could you update this question with one of the `status` tags so that we can know what the progress is?

Answer (score 3):

A user script was made to help with this issue.

[AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)

Using this, you can save certain comments to be reused for later. When you click "Add a comment" it gives you a link that says "auto". When you click on it, it gives you some pre-made comments plus any comments that you have saved with it. I would definitely recommend using it.

Comment: This doesn't work for the mobile app though and only in some browsers, so it's only a temporary work around