# Fixing Request for Sources Problem

Tags: feature-request, references

[Recently](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/695/shortcut-for-request-to-include-sources), I requested a shortcut `[sources]` for the comments to include sources.

Reading old questions and answers, I've come across the following banner below a question:

[image]

I assume it has been placed there in February 2016.

What happened to these kind of banners? I start to really like them. Maybe it is a feature that we could implement. I thought of an overall solution for the whole issue with the request to include sources and have come up with the following:

1. **Flagging**:
   I think we should be able to flag posts as *lacking references* or similar. [Since we have decided](http://(https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers)) that all answers **must** include references, answers lacking references violate the community guidelines and we should be able to notify the moderators.
2. **Comment**:
   Even more important than notifying the moderation is notifying the user. Most new users don't know about the community guideline, and some old and experienced users might have forgotten. This will give them the chance to update their answers with references.
   Similarly as comments are auto-created when flagging something as duplicate, I think a comment should be auto created when flagging an answer as *lacking references*.
3. **Banner**:
   Both comment and banner would be overkill. I prefer a comment, but we could also try to get rid of these comments (as they usually start arguments about why, what and how) and display the banner. I'd leave it up to the community to decide.