# Do we need a banner providing help for people considering suicide

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This answer to [Is death due to drug-induced respiratory arrest painful?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/is-death-due-to-drug-induced-respiratory-arrest-painful/13992#13992) made me think we need a banner that can be added to questions that basically says *if you are thinking about suicide please get some help* and then have links website and/or phone numbers.

To clarify my position, I think there are questions that are pretty clearly asking about suicide. I think these should be rapidly closed with a comment providing help and a flag for moderators to call in the SE team so they can do their thing. The linked question is not one of those, in my opinion. I think it is asking a real on-topic question and that the user has no intention of committing suicide. That said, a future user looking to commit suicide might someday find the question. I would like to see a banner on these types of question so that future users who might be thinking about suicide can get the help they need.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/whats-the-official-se-response-to-serious-mentions-of-suicide-or-self-harm-in-p

Comment: @JohnP in terms of content, that is what I was thinking, but the application would be to preface questions that may be found by people considering suicide

Comment: Mmmm...not sure it's really appropriate. If you have a question on Academics about how to better catch students you suspect of plagiarizing, do you put a disclaimer on it so any students seeing would know how to better plagiarize? That's not the best example, sorry.

Comment: @JohnP the example is close, but we don't have a special handling procedure for questions asking about how to cheat.

Comment: True, I was trying to come up with an equivalent, and there isn't really a good one. One thing to consider though, is would a banner disclaimer have the opposite effect? i.e. "Since there's a disclaimer, this must be a GREAT method to do that!"

Comment: @JohnP maybe (you could make that an answer), but then the header on the linked answer should be deleted.

Comment: This is an interesting question, for sure. I'd be interested in Shog's take on it, or another CM. I was just about to suggest it be an overall meta rather than just here, but not sure it's really sitewide applicable.

Comment: @JohnP I asked a [question about suicide questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257710/mod-only-tool-for-posts-that-mention-suicide) on meta once, not doing that again.

Comment: Heh. DV to oblivion...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to substitute a banner with my headline and I hope it will work well. My intention was not that the OP was about to commit suicide but that parts of the answer could be seen as a guide and hence I included the banner. I was considering for a long time whether to post at all.

The substitute will suffice. A banner is handy and neat, but not deeply needed.

In my honest opinion, we have so many unresolved feature requests that are neither declined nor accepted that I would prioritise:

- [Linking Personal Close Reason to DoctorWhom's answer](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/763/8212)
- [Improving our How To Ask page](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/761/8212)
- [We Need a Crystal Clear "Rules for Asking Questions" - Agree or no?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/739/8212)
- [Fixing Request for Sources Problem](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/8212)
- [Shortcut for Request to Include sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/695/8212)